# Web service values not appearing in label

Tags: ios, mysql, json, swift

I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working.  I have a web service that extracts names and title from a MYSQL database.  Its working.  I have even added a print statement to test both the JSON results as well as my html formatted string.  For some reason though when I go to write it out to a label, it shows nothing.  Any help would be appreciative.  Below is the full code.

```
import UIKit

class ContactsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var contactsLabel: UILabel!
    //Our web service url
    let URL_GET_TEAMS:String = "http://www.example.com/apps/getcontacts.php"

    var myLabel : String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        //created NSURL
        let requestURL = NSURL(string: URL_GET_TEAMS)


        //creating NSMutableURLRequest
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)

        //setting the method to post
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        //creating a task to send the post request
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
            data, response, error in

            //exiting if there is some error
            if error != nil{
                print("error is \(error)")
                return;
            }

            //parsing the response
            do {
                //converting resonse to NSDictionary
                var teamJSON: NSDictionary!
                teamJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                //getting the JSON array teams from the response
                let teams: NSArray = teamJSON["contacts"] as! NSArray

                //looping through all the json objects in the array teams
                for i in 0 ..< teams.count{

                    //getting the data at each index
                    let teamId:String = (teams[i] as! NSDictionary)["title"] as! String!
                    let teamName:String = (teams[i] as! NSDictionary) ["name"] as! String!



                    //displaying the data
                    print("id -> ", teamId)
                    print("name -> ", teamName)
                    print("===================")
                    print("")
                    self.myLabel = self.myLabel + "<font size='5'><b>" + teamId + "</font>:</b> " + "<font size='5'>" + teamName + "</font><br /><br />"
                    print(self.myLabel)
                }

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        //executing the task
        task.resume()

        let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(data: myLabel.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode,allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
        contactsLabel.attributedText = attrStr
        contactsLabel.sizeToFit()
    }

 }
```

Comment: Do you get any data when you print teamId and teamName?

Comment: if you are getting data in teamId and teamName then put your  self.myLabel = self.myLabel + "<font size='5'><b>" + teamId + "</font>:</b> " + "<font size='5'>" + teamName + "</font><br /><br />"  code in main thread as DispatchQueue.main.async {
  ...your label code here..
}

Comment: Yes I am getting data when I print out the teamid and teamName

Comment: put label code in main thread as I wrote in above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `URLSession` runs in a background thread that is asynchronous, so you have to go back to the main thread in the closure.

```
import UIKit

class ContactsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var contactsLabel: UILabel!
    //Our web service url
    let URL_GET_TEAMS:String = "http://www.example.com/apps/getcontacts.php"

    var myLabel : String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        //created NSURL
        let requestURL = NSURL(string: URL_GET_TEAMS)


        //creating NSMutableURLRequest
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)

        //setting the method to post
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        //creating a task to send the post request
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
            data, response, error in

            //exiting if there is some error
            if error != nil{
                print("error is \(error)")
                return;
            }

            //parsing the response
            do {
                //converting resonse to NSDictionary
                var teamJSON: NSDictionary!
                teamJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                //getting the JSON array teams from the response
                let teams: NSArray = teamJSON["contacts"] as! NSArray

                //looping through all the json objects in the array teams
                for i in 0 ..< teams.count{

                    //getting the data at each index
                    let teamId:String = (teams[i] as! NSDictionary)["title"] as! String!
                    let teamName:String = (teams[i] as! NSDictionary) ["name"] as! String!



                    //displaying the data
                    print("id -> ", teamId)
                    print("name -> ", teamName)
                    print("===================")
                    print("")
                    self.myLabel = self.myLabel + "<font size='5'><b>" + teamId + "</font>:</b> " + "<font size='5'>" + teamName + "</font><br /><br />"
                    print(self.myLabel)
                }

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(data: myLabel.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode,allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
                contactsLabel.attributedText = attrStr
                contactsLabel.sizeToFit()
            }
        }
        //executing the task
        task.resume()
    }

 }
```

When you call `resume()`, the task runs in a background, so the label is immediately updated while the text still has not changed. This is a common but confusing error – remember that a `dataTask` runs in a background thread, therefore update the UI inside its clousure.

Comment: Well I learned something new today.  I'm not sure I fully understand what the dispatchQueue does but I'll read the doc and get a better understanding of it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Something a little strange that I've noticed.  When I bring up the app, if I immediately tap the contacts sometimes it won't load anything, if I go back out and then come in again the data is there.  I never see that delay when calling the webservice directly from a browser.  I'm wondering if it would make better sense to move the code to the front end of the app and then pass it off to contacts view when needed.